# AchartEngine annotations

Tags: android, annotations, achartengine

everywhere i look, the only information I can find says to add them via the following code

```
series.addAnnotation("Hello!!", 1, 1);
```

However, When I try it in my code (with the proper series name) I get an error message that says addAnnotation is not supported. Can someone please clear this up for me? thanks!

Comment: I do have the latest version of achartengine, however, there are no XYseries in my chart. So, I don't know where i'd add the annotation code :/

Comment: ...posted it below, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must download a recent version of the library. For example, get the night build from [here](https://repository-achartengine.forge.cloudbees.com/snapshot/org/achartengine/achartengine/1.1.0/).

In your code, replace the last line (the one where you return the chart view) with:

```
XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = buildBarDataset(titles, values);
XYSeries series = dataset.getSeriesAt(0);
series.addAnnotation("Vacation", 6, 30);
return ChartFactory.getBarChartView(context, dataset, renderer, Type.STACKED);
```

Comment: IT WORKS!! Thank you so much, I really appreciate it...you're the man. you wouldn't know if it's possible to change the annotation color or size, would you?

Comment: @JP409 maybe a little late but u can use 1.2.0 to set annotation format ,see [this](https://code.google.com/p/achartengine/issues/detail?id=280)

Comment: Do annotations not work unless there is a point with at least the same X value? or is this only a TimeSeries constraint?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code...

```
public View getView(Context context) {

    String[] titles = new String[] { "2008", "2007" };
    List<double[]> values = new ArrayList<double[]>();
    values.add(new double[] { 240, 210, 60, 40 });
    values.add(new double[] { htmlHelper.grec, htmlHelper.gwhite, htmlHelper.gim, htmlHelper.gfit });
    int[] colors = new int[] { Color.rgb(255, 255, 255),
            Color.rgb(25, 25, 112) };
    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = buildBarRenderer(colors);

    switch (context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi) {

    /* Done*/
    case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH:
        renderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(29);
        renderer.setChartTitleTextSize(60);
        renderer.setLabelsTextSize(29);
        renderer.setLegendTextSize(50);
        renderer.setChartValuesTextSize(40);
        break;

    /*done*/
    case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH:
        renderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(15);
        renderer.setChartTitleTextSize(47);
        renderer.setLabelsTextSize(19);
        renderer.setLegendTextSize(1);
        renderer.setChartValuesTextSize(40);
        break;

    case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW:
        renderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(24);
        renderer.setChartTitleTextSize(25);
        renderer.setLabelsTextSize(9);
        renderer.setLegendTextSize(10);
        renderer.setChartValuesTextSize(20);
        break;

    default:
        renderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(39);
        renderer.setChartTitleTextSize(35);
        renderer.setLabelsTextSize(20);
        renderer.setLegendTextSize(2);
        renderer.setChartValuesTextSize(40);
        break;
    }

    setChartSettings(renderer, "Gym Attendance", "", "", 0.5, 12.5, 0,
            24000, Color.BLACK, Color.BLACK);
    renderer.getSeriesRendererAt(0).setDisplayChartValues(false);
    renderer.getSeriesRendererAt(1).setDisplayChartValues(true);
    renderer.setShowLegend(false);
    renderer.setMargins(new int[] { 80, 10, 60, 10 });
    renderer.addXTextLabel(1, "Rec. Hall" + "\n" + ce);
    renderer.addXTextLabel(2, "White" + "\n" + "Building" + "\n"
            + wh);
    renderer.addXTextLabel(3, "IM" + "\n" + "Building" + "\n" + imm);
    renderer.addXTextLabel(4, "Fitness Loft" + "\n" + fi);
    renderer.setXLabelsColor(Color.rgb(0, 0, 0));
    renderer.setYLabelsColor(0, Color.BLACK);
    renderer.setYLabels(10);
    renderer.setXLabels(0);
    renderer.setXAxisMin(0);
    renderer.setXAxisMax(5);
    renderer.setYAxisMin(0);
    renderer.setYAxisMax(250);
    renderer.setAxesColor(Color.BLACK);
    renderer.setXLabelsAlign(Align.CENTER);
    renderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.LEFT);
    renderer.setPanEnabled(false, false);
    // renderer.setZoomEnabled(false);
    renderer.setZoomRate(1.1f);
    renderer.setBarSpacing(0.5f);
    renderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
    renderer.getSeriesRendererAt(1).setGradientEnabled(true);
    renderer.getSeriesRendererAt(1).setGradientStart(0,
            Color.rgb(192, 192, 192));
    renderer.getSeriesRendererAt(1).setGradientStop(45,
            Color.rgb(25, 25, 112));
    renderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(220, 220, 220));
    renderer.setMarginsColor(Color.rgb(248, 248, 255));
    renderer.setOrientation(Orientation.HORIZONTAL);
    renderer.setZoomEnabled(false, false);

    return ChartFactory.getBarChartView(context,
            buildBarDataset(titles, values), renderer, Type.STACKED);

}
```

Thanks so much for taking a look! At first I had the graph in frame layout with textviews but that doesn't work once I started testing on different screen sizes and pixel densities.